# tikz: correct syntax in \draw points

Tags: positioning, nodes

Let x and y be two nodes.
Whith `\draw[blue] (x)--(y);` a straight line can be drawn between these two nodes.
If by chance I had to draw a straight line starting for example, from a point that is 2 millimeters from the right of node a, how can I proceed? There is something in the form `\draw[blue] (2 mm right of x) - (y)`?

Comment: You say "let x and y be two nodes " and then you use a and b. Is it a typo? Notice that lines between two node are really drawn between the borders of the nodes, if they exist. Posting a complete, compilable example would be much better.

Comment: yes, sorry! Now I put the right nodes name

Answer (score 6):

Some possibilities:

- `\draw[blue] ([xshift=2 mm]  a) - (b);`
- `\draw[red, shorten <=2 mm] (a) - (b);`
- `\draw[teal] (a.east) ++ (2mm,0) -- (b);`

etc.

**Addendum:**
Regarding your comments:

- For all possible option you should read Ti*k*Z  package manula. In section *13 Specifying Coordinates* (page 138) are describe many (all) possible options.
- Possible solutions:

  - `\draw[red, shorten >=2 mm] (a) - (b);`
  - for other possible solution the context of drawing this lines had to be know. For example, you can increase `outer sep` of nodes, etc.

Comment: Nice! What if I wanted the point 2mm from the left of b as the end point?

Comment: @user3713179, than you go to read "Ti*k*Z" manual ... :-) See addendum to answer (will appear soon).